# Suppress SELECT output based on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, guid

I have a query here to search the entire database for a specific GUID that I choose.  Right now, it's doing exactly what it's programmed to do: cycle through all column/table combo's and output a table that may or may not contain information.  I would like to change this to output ONLY tables that contain results.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE 
    @tab_list NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @col_list NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @IDquery NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @srvName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @getList CURSOR

SET @srvName = 'Server_Name'

SET @getList = CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT [TABLE_NAME]
        ,[COLUMN_NAME]
    FROM [Server_Name].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
    WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] LIKE '%id'
        AND [DATA_TYPE] LIKE 'uniqueidentifier'
    ORDER BY [TABLE_NAME] ASC

OPEN @getList

FETCH NEXT FROM @getList INTO @tab_list, @col_list

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN       
    PRINT @tab_list + ' -- ' + @col_list

    SET @IDquery = 
        'SELECT *' + 
        ' FROM ' + @srvName + '.dbo.' + @tab_list + 
        ' WHERE ' + @col_list + ' = (''GUID_HERE'')' +
        ' AND ' + @col_list + ' IS NOT NULL'

    --PRINT @IDquery
    EXEC (@IDquery)
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getList INTO @tab_list, @col_list
END

CLOSE @getList
DEALLOCATE @getList
```

It does do it's job right now, but horribly inefficiently.  As I mentioned before, as it searches for this GUID, it outputs any table it searches, even those that have no matches.  I want it to output ONLY tables that contain matches, I don't care how.  I honestly don't even care if all that it returns is a table and column that the thing finds a match in (meaning I'd have to manually hit that table).  I just want cleaner output and cannot seem to put the answer together.

EDIT: So I like the promise that temp tables offer, though I'm running into a bit of a snag.  Here's what I have:

```
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN       
        PRINT @tab_list + ' -- ' + @col_list

        SET @IDquery = 
            'SELECT * INTO #temporary' + 
            ' FROM ' + @srvName + '.dbo.' + @tab_list + 
            ' WHERE ' + @col_list + ' = (''GUID_HERE'')' +
            ' AND ' + @col_list + ' IS NOT NULL'

        --PRINT @IDquery
        EXEC (@IDquery)
        FETCH NEXT FROM @getList INTO @tab_list, @col_list
    END

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
SELECT @ FROM #temporary

DROP DATABASE #temporary
CLOSE @getList
DEALLOCATE @getList
```

I may be mistaken on how temp tables work, but I'm seeing no table output with this code.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of selecting straight from the table, instead insert the results into a temporary table.  Then check the `@@ROWCOUNT` to determine if any records were found by the `SELECT... INTO`, and if so, select the results from the temp table:

```
SET @IDquery = '
    SELECT * INTO #Temp
    FROM ' + @srvName + '.dbo.' + @tab_list + ' 
    WHERE ' + @col_list + ' = (''GUID_HERE'')
    AND ' + @col_list + ' IS NOT NULL

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        SELECT * FROM #Temp
'

--PRINT @IDquery
EXEC (@IDquery)

FETCH NEXT FROM @getList INTO @tab_list, @col_list
```

Comment: Thanks what I was thinking of trying.  As soon as I get a few minutes of free time to try that, I'll report back.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @mistawac If you create the temporary table in a dynamic sql statement, it will be scoped to that statement, and be dropped as soon as the `EXEC(@IDquery)` command completes.  You'll have to select from the temporary table in the same scope it is created... so you'll have to include the `@@ROWCOUNT` check and conditional select in your dynamic sql statement like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You're spawning another process when using the EXEC, so your temp table is dropped and recreated with each pass.  Try using the same code, but with a global temp table (`##temporary`).

Also I'm assuming `SELECT @ FROM #temporary` was a typo and you actually ran `SELECT * FROM #temporary`.